# WinForms phantom borders

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have an application at work, which was written in VB.Net winforms with VS2008. It has been updated to VS2015 recently; however, some phantom borders have started appearing on the UI. Most of the controls/UI are all custom controls, but hopefully someone here may have some idea as to why these are appearing now after being built with 2015. (I compiled the same code on 2008, and the borders aren't there).

The screenshot below shows the "phantom borders" in action.

[image: UI Phantom Borders]

It may be difficult to see, but the light gray lines on the left of the text is the "phantom border". While this doesn't look like a major problem in this case, it is much MUCH worse when on the whole UI, with all the other controls doing very much the same thing.

Hopefully someone has some ideas as I am fresh out!

I have tried - disabling all borders in the controls, enabling then disabling (to make sure there is no cached state). Checking all the properties on the user controls to make sure I am not missing a property.

Comment: I'll go out on the proverbial limb a bit and point you to declaring your application to be DPI Aware.  Start a new Winform project in VS2015.  Go to Project Menu->ProjName Properties-<Application Tab->View Window Settings Button to open the app.manifest file.  Copy the `<application>` block that has `dpiAware` tag in it to your old application.

Comment: @TnTinMn interesting thought! Ill have a look tomorrow. Do you know roughly when these settings for  dpi awareness came in? The thing i found most odd was that if i built it, it would render the same on win7 and win10, not just 10. Must admit it is quite a perplexing problem.

Comment: DPI awareness has been a moving target going back to XP.  A good summary  table is presented in [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx#high_dpi_tutorial).  The most likely culprit is DPI Virtualization that started in Vista but it took a few years for monitors to change out so that issues became apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical. Ask the question and then the answer sort of appears!

The problem was due to the "OnPaintBackground" method being overridden in the base user controls.

It seems like Windows 10/vs2015 (not sure which element of that equation) has changed the way it does pixel calculations.

Where the base controls would get the background image of the form behind it, to do a manual "transparency" for the user control, the size would be 1 pixel too small on the width and/or height.

The code before (that created the phantom borders):

```vb
Dim srcRec As Rectangle = Bounds
srcRec.Offset(backgroundSource.Origin)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(backgroundSource.BackgroundImage, 0, 0, srcRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

As you can see, it grabs the size of the control, then gets the background portion behind it, and draws that image as its own background.

The corrected code (that gets rid of the phantom borders):

```vb
Dim srcRec As Rectangle = Bounds
srcRec.Width +=1 
srcRec.Height +=1
srcRec.Offset(backgroundSource.Origin)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(backgroundSource.BackgroundImage, -1, -1, srcRec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

This seems to fix the problem, hiding the phantom borders and rendering the UI correctly.

Thank you to anyone who at least looked at this problem! It is difficult to summarise the problem from a codebase I cannot share. Hopefully this can help other people in the future.